# How to get child value for my RecyclerView when use Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use `dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatItem.class);` to save value that is `name` and `msg` from FirebaseDatabase.

When I use `firstRoot.addChildEventListener` my textRight of recyclerView value is empty, so I try to use `addChildEventListener` in different root that is `secondRoot.addChildEventListener` and `thirdRoot.addChildEventListener`, it will cause crash.

I don't know another way to get it. Can someone teach me how to finish it?
 Thanks in advance.

Here is my  ChatRoom class for RecyclerView:

```
public class ChatRoom extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String roomName, userName;

    private Button sendMessage;
    private EditText typeMessage;
    private String temp_key;

    private DatabaseReference firstRoot;
    private DatabaseReference secondRoot;
    private DatabaseReference thirdRoot;

    private RecyclerView recyclerChat;
    private ArrayList<ChatItem> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerChatAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

        initViews();

        roomName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("room_name");
        userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userName");

        setTitle("Chat Name:" + roomName);

        firstRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatGroup");//specify first child

        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                secondRoot = firstRoot.child(roomName);

                Map<String, Object> mapKey = new HashMap<>();
                temp_key = firstRoot.push().getKey();//create key control json tree
                firstRoot.updateChildren(mapKey);


                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name", userName);
                map.put("msg", typeMessage.getText().toString());

                thirdRoot = secondRoot.child(temp_key);
                thirdRoot.updateChildren(map);

                typeMessage.setText("");
            }
        });

        firstRoot.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ChatItem chatItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatItem.class);//i save value to my java bean class

                listData.add(chatItem);
                recyclerChat.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);//just let the latest data below
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        //        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(manager);

        adapter = new RecyclerChatAdapter(this, listData);
        recyclerChat.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
        typeMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
        recyclerChat = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerChat);
    }
}
```

My javabean:

```
public class ChatItem {
    private String name;
    private String msg;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

My RecyclerViewAdapter about onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textRight.setText(itemList.get(position).getMsg());
    }
```

Here is my json tree:
[image]

I try to use constructor for my javabean , it's till no working:

```
public ChatItem(){
}

public ChatItem(String name, String msg) {
    this.name = name;
    this.msg = msg;
}
```

I had set permission too:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My question is `holder.textRight.setText(itemList.get(position).getMsg());` is null , i can't get it for my recyclerView

I use `ChatItem chatItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatItem.class);` works like this json tree:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview

Comment: thanks for responding , i will try it , but i really want to know hot to get the value and show recyclerView in this case.

Comment: And that's what the guide shows you

Comment: what step should i change , i can't figure out like FirebaseRecyclerAdapter , where is it ?

Comment: It is part of that whole Github repo I linked you to. You include that library in Gradle. Super useful for the exact thing you are trying to do

Comment: Oh i got it , it use by gradle , thanks for that . By the way , i really want to know ChatItem chatItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatItem.class); why is null :(

Comment: Because firebase can't map your data completely is generally the reason

Comment: Basically, `Chat1` is your `DataSnapShot`, which is something like a `List<ChatItem>` itself, therefore can't be assigned to a `ChatItem`

Comment: Really !? but i try it succeed in another json tree , just like i have updated , what's different between them ?

Comment: ChatGroup2 has no time field?

Comment: it should be , i just didn't put message after i enter code about variable time